# Stop function after set amount of time

Tags: function, audio, time, p5.js

I'm making a sketch (in p5js) where sounds will be played based on the location of your nose. Now I have two sets of sounds: nature sounds and city sounds. I put them both in different functions so the nature sounds will start playing after a set amount of time.

Now I can't figure out how I can stop the city sounds from playing after a certain amount of time. In this sketch I've tried calling a function that would stop the makeCITYSounds function after a few seconds, but it doesn't work.

I have copied some pieces of the code that are relevant. The sounds all play, that's fine. I just want to stop the citySounds after a few seconds.

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(1500, 1200);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.hide();
  poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelLoaded);
  poseNet.on('pose', gotPoses);
  //timeout from the start.
  setTimeout(makeNATURESound, 60000);
  setTimeout(makeCITYSound,1000);
  setTimeout(stopCitySound,5000);
}

function makeCITYSound(){
  if(noseX < 50){
    if(!kids_Amsterdam.isPlaying()){
      kids_Amsterdam.play();
    }
  }else if(noseX >= 50 && noseX <100){
      if(!bells.isPlaying()){
        bells.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >= 100 && noseX <150){
      if(!insideSubway.isPlaying()){
        insideSubway.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >= 150 && noseX <200){
      if(!subwayStation.isPlaying()){
        subwayStation.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >= 200 && noseX <250){
      if(!seoulMarket.isPlaying()){
        seoulMarket.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=250 && noseX <300){
      if(!onBridge.isPlaying()){
        onBridge.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=300 && noseX <350){
      if(!kids_Amsterdam.isPlaying()){
        kids_Amsterdam.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=350 && noseX <400){
      if(!insideSubway.isPlaying()){
        insideSubway.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=400 && noseX <450){
      if(!fountain.isPlaying()){
        fountain.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=450 && noseX <500){
      if(!insects.isPlaying()){
        insects.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=500 && noseX <550){
      if(!onBridge.isPlaying()){
        onBridge.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=550 && noseX <600){
      if(!birds.isPlaying()){
        birds.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=600 && noseX <650){
      if(!insideSubway.isPlaying()){
        insideSubway.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=650 && noseX <700){
      if(!kids_Amsterdam.isPlaying()){
        kids_Amsterdam.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=700 && noseX <750){
      if(!bells.isPlaying()){
        bells.play();
      }
    }
    setTimeout(makeCITYSound, 1000);
}


function makeNATURESound(){
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  // ellipse(noseX, noseY,10);
  // image(leaf,noseX, noseY,50,50);
  // for(z=0; z<leaf.length; z++){
  //   image(leaf[z], noseX, noseY,50,50);
  // }
  let leaf = random(leafs);
  image(leaf, noseX, noseY,random(50,100),random(50,100));

  if(noseX < 50){
    if(!birds.isPlaying()){
      birds.play();
    }
  }else if(noseX >= 50 && noseX <100){
      if(!insects.isPlaying()){
        insects.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >= 100 && noseX <150){
      if(!water2.isPlaying()){
        water2.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >= 150 && noseX <200){
      if(!fountain.isPlaying()){
        fountain.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >= 200 && noseX <250){
      if(!birdsMorning.isPlaying()){
        birdsMorning.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=250 && noseX <300){
      if(!birdsMorning.isPlaying()){
        birdsMorning.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=300 && noseX <350){
      if(!autumnLeaves.isPlaying()){
        autumnLeaves.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=350 && noseX <400){
      if(!birds.isPlaying()){
        birds.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=400 && noseX <450){
      if(!fountain.isPlaying()){
        fountain.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=450 && noseX <500){
      if(!insects.isPlaying()){
        insects.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=500 && noseX <550){
      if(!autumnLeaves.isPlaying()){
        autumnLeaves.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=550 && noseX <600){
      if(!birds.isPlaying()){
        birds.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=600 && noseX <650){
      if(!water2.isPlaying()){
        water2.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=650 && noseX <700){
      if(!insects.isPlaying()){
        insects.play();
      }
    }else if(noseX >=700 && noseX <750){
      if(!birdsMorning.isPlaying()){
        birdsMorning.play();
      }
    }
  //timeout in between poses.
  setTimeout(makeNATURESound, 1000);
}

function stopCitySound(){
  makeCITYSound().noLoop();
}
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the `noLoop` function. Unfortunately there are actually several `noLoop` functions. One is a global p5.js function that discontinues automatic calls to the `draw` function (see [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop)). More likely the one you are trying to call is the [instance function on p5.MediaElement](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.MediaElement/noLoop). However, in any case the way you are trying to call it should result in an error like `Cannot read property 'noLoop' of undefined`. This is because `makeCITYSound` has no return value. In order for this to work `makeCITYSound` would have to return a single `p5.MediaElement` instance. But that's probably not what you want to do either because it doesn't make sense to make a new call to `makeCITYSound()` and then only stop a single `p5.MediaElement` from looping.

```
  //             \/-- this doesn't make sense
  makeCITYSound().noLoop();
```

From the code you have shared it isn't clear that you are using looping at all with these `p5.MediaElement`s so it's a little hard to say what the best approach is. If things are looping and you want to stop that you need to call noLoop on each `p5.MediaElement` instance (i.e. `bells.noLoop()`). If you want to stop new city sounds from playing regardless of the value of `noseX` and `noseY` then you need to discontinue the repeated calls to `makeCITYSounds` that results from the last line of that function: `setTimeout(makeCITYSound, 1000)`. To do this you just need to add a local variable to determine whether those calls should continue:

```
let stopCITYSound = false;
function makeCITYSound() {
  if (stopCITYSound) {
    // Return without playing any new sounds or scheduling another call to makeCITYSound
    return;
  }

  // ... Your existing code
}

function stopCitySound(){
  stopCITYSound = true;
}
```